# C definition formatting question

Tags: c++, c, objective-c

I am thinking about changing my formatting style.  I have been doing this:

```
char *foo(IULabel *label, char *buffer) {
    UITextView  *tv;
    int         i;
    int         *j;

...
}
```

and I am thinking that it might be easier to understand if I were to write:

```
char * foo(IULabel * label, char * buffer) {
    UITextView *    tv;
    int             i;
    int *           j;

...
}
```

or

```
char* foo(IULabel* label, char* buffer) {
    UITextView*    tv;
    int             i;
    int*            j;

...
}
```

How do you do it?

Comment: Formatting style is subjective: I find aligning the variable names like you do really ugly, and that it leads to refactoring pain-in-the-*ss.

Comment: I have felt that pain.  But how else can I be OCD?

Comment: I realize it is subjective, but there is much to be learned from the reasoning behind each person's choices.

I admit though, I have no idea how select an answer for this question, as there really is no wrong one (except maybe if some person says, "If you don't format it this way, you're an *¢#$@!")

Answer (score 13):

I use the style:

```
char *x;
```

because this logically reflects how C parses declarations - the "definition follows use" rule.  Don't think "`x` is a `char *`", think "`*x` is a `char`".

That lets you correctly parse definitions such as these:

```
const char *x;
```

(`*x` is a `const char`)

```
char * const x;
```

(`x`, constant, after applying `*` is a char)

```
char *x, y, **z;
```

(`*x` is a `char`, `y` is a `char`, `**z` is a char)

**Addendum:**

Responding to a couple of the comments...

The idea that declarations can be written as `TYPE LABEL;` ends up breaking down for more complex types, even if you ban multiple declarations on one line (which I don't agree with, either: `int i, j;` has always been idiomatic C).  For example, if I want to declare `x` as "pointer to array of 10 char", then the type is `char (*)[10]` (this is how you'd write it in a cast, for example).  But you can't use the `TYPE LABEL;` pattern:

```
char (*)[10] x;    /* Not valid C :( */
```

Function pointers are another example.  The usual rejoinder at this point is "Always use a `typedef` for complex types like that!", and here I feel we must simply part ways and agree to disagree.  Either you consider the logical inconsistencies and restrictions ("declare only one variable per line", "always build up complex types from simple typedefs") an appropriate price to pay for making declarations look the way you feel they should, or you don't.

In response to the Stroustrup comment I note that K&R uses the `char *x` style, and here it seems we have the root of the C / C++ divergence on this matter of style.

Comment: For what it is worth Bjarne Stroustrup uses char* x in his FAQ rather than char *x.  I find reading type definitions easy if you read right to left, so in the examples above 1) x is a pointer to a const char, 2) x is a const pointer to a char, 3) Don't put multiple definitions one line - see cschol's comment below.

Comment: char* x; Is more C++ like as the type of 'x' is 'pointer to char'. The only counter argument is by people that say you can do char* x,y; and 'y' is only a char. The counter counter argument is that has always been considered bad style even in the days of C.

Answer (score 4):

A professor once told me in university "the most important rule of style of consistency." As long as you are doing the same thing everywhere, it doesn't matter. If you are the only one working on the project, do whatever looks best to you. Otherwise bring it up with the other devs, form a consensus and work with that.

Comment: Consistency sure is the key, but I wouldn't say that style "doesn't matter"

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't matter, I said it's the most important aspect of good style. 

A downvote is unjustified.

Comment: Ummmm.. quoting you:  "As long as you are doing the same thing everywhere, it doesn't matter. "

Comment: I was being terse. If you would like me to be more elaborate
"It doesn't matter *which of the style schemes for variable definition you presented* that you use in your code, so long as you pick one and use it consistently."

Answer (score 4):

Most C programmers I know write:

```
int *x;
```

Most C++ programmers I know write:

```
int* x;
```

I attribute this to the fact that C programmers think of x as "a pointer to a chunk of memory that is to be interpreted as an int", whereas C++ programmers think of x more as "an object of type int*"

I'm an assembly programmer, but I like the first style.

Answer (score 3):

Coding style is completely subjective, but I like this:

```
char* foo = "Foo";
```

It makes more sense to me because the type is *pointer to char", so it seems natural that the pointer notation would appear next to the type specifier.

EDIT:  And I think that stephentyrone is probably correct in his assumption.

Answer (score 3):

Your first one will lead to less confusion. Otherwise:

```
int* x, y;
```

At first glance, they appear to be the same type, but they're not. The first is a pointer-to-int, and the second is int. This is much clearer:

```
int *x, y;
```

Comment: Don't put two definitions on one line and there is also no problem.

Answer (score 2):

One of the downsides to formats like this:

```
UITextView *tv;
int         i;
int        *j;
```

is that someday you'll need to add another variable whose type has more characters than `UITextview` :

```
UITextView *tv;
int         i;
int        *j;
SomeOtherDataType t;
```

which presents you with the choice of either messing up the column layout and leaving a **[broken window<sup>1</sup>](http://www.sjvgreens.org/broken.shtml)**, or adding spaces to the other variables and committing the revision-control atrocity of **Introducing Unnecessary Reformatting that Obscures the Material Changes**.

My preference is to declare variables one per line, ordered by type when it makes sense, and sacrifice some vertical space in favor of readability and ease of commenting:

```
UITextView
   *tv;         // Data to be edited by the user.
int
    i,          // One-based index (for compatibility with BASIC)
   *j;          // Will be malloc'ed -- free it later.
SomeOtherDataType
    t;          // See p. 23 of req'ts doc for details.
```

I'm not completely satisfied with this, however, and would be interested to see additional solutions.  What are yours?

---

<sup>1</sup> I'd be remiss if I didn't mention that the entire article is quoted [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/Atlantic%20Monthly%20-%20Broken%20Windows.htm).  Where's that $20 you owe me, Jeff?  :-)

Comment: I have felt the pain of the unnecessary revision-control change.  It's even worse when it happens when you realize you've had spaces instead of a tab and want to do a local replace of those spaces...

Comment: Many revision-control tools will either convert spaces/tabs to your preference or ignore whitespace when comparing files.  But, like a mosquito, it's a tiny problem that's still terribly annoying.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether language im using, also on the IDE automatic capabilities.

In C# I dont align line endings, as there is comments separating declarations.

But in VHDL where declarations are common and represent wiring I prefer to align line endings like your 2nd format.

Give it a try and see which one will be more comfortable and time saving.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is surely subjective, but if i were to align up the names, then i would put the modifiers directly next to them and align the names directly

```
char *foo(IULabel *label, char *buffer) {
  UITextView *tv;
  int         i;
  int        *j;

  ...
}
```

But usually, i just do

```
char *foo(IULabel *label, char *buffer) {
  int i;
  int *j;
  UITextView *tv;
  ...
}
```

I try to order things from "short lines" to "long lines", if the order wouldn't matter otherwise :)